# semPLS package backcalculating influence

Tags: r

I'm doing a PLS regression using the `semPLS` package in R and was wondering something

This is the example from `?sempls`:

```
library(semPLS)
data(ECSImobi)
ecsi <- sempls(model=ECSImobi, data=mobi, wscheme="pathWeighting")
ecsi
```

We see `IMAG1-5` is connected to the latent variable of `Image`. Each one has an outer loading between 0.57 and 0.77. `Image` now is connected to the variable `Expectation` and has a beta coefficient of 0.505. 
Now my question is:
Is it possible to "back-calculate" the influence of 0.505 to each `IMAG1-5`-variable?

After looking at the model specifications and formula you could just do 0.505/0.77, and so on. But that doesn't make very much sense because the higher the correlation between `IMAG1-5` and `Image` the lower the influence on `Expectation` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure about this, but since there is no answer here, I'll give it a shot.

If I understand correctly, what you want is kind of an effect size.

This can be calculated in the structural model for exogenous latent variables according to [Cohen,1988, p.410-413](http://www.lrdc.pitt.edu/schneider/p2465/Readings/Cohen,%201988%20%28Statistical%20Power,%20273-406%29.pdf) with the effect size f².

[image]

So if you want the effect of a exogenous Variable on an endogenous Variable you calculate the model two times, first with that specific exogenous Variable and second without it. Now you have two R² values of that endogenous Variable, which you put in the formula of Cohen.

An effect size of 0.02, 0.15 and 0.35 are weak, moderate and strong effects.

The R Code for the effect size of "Image" on "Loyalty" would look like this:

```
library(semPLS)
data(ECSImobi)
ecsi <- sempls(model=ECSImobi, data=mobi, wscheme="pathWeighting")
ecsi

#estimate model without LV "Image"
excl_image_ecsi <- sempls(model=removeLVs(ECSImobi,"Image"), data=mobi, wscheme="pathWeighting")
excl_image_ecsi

#rSquared of "Loyalty" with exogenous variable "Image"
rSquared(ecsi)[7]

#rSquared of "Loyalty" without exogenous variable "Image"
rSquared(excl_image_ecsi)[6]

#calculate effect size of "Image" on "Loyalty"
(fSquared <- (rSquared(ecsi)[7]-rSquared(excl_image_ecsi)[6])/(1-rSquared(ecsi)[7]))
```

Effect size of "Image" on "Loyalty" is 0.03 , which can be considered as weak.

So here are some ideas for calculating the effect size of an indicator based on the previous procedure of Cohen.

First estimate the model without the MV "IMAG1"

```
excl_IMAG1_ecsi <- sempls(model=removeMVs(ECSImobi,"IMAG1"), data=mobi, wscheme="pathWeighting")
```

Then calculate the f² of "IMAG1" on "Expectation"

```
#get rSquared of "Expectation"
rSquared(ecsi)[2]

#get new rSquared of "Expectation"
rSquared(excl_IMAG1_ecsi)[2]

#effect size of "IMAG1" on Expectation
(fSquared <- (rSquared(ecsi)[2]-rSquared(excl_IMAG1_ecsi)[2])/(1-rSquared(ecsi)[2]))
```

The effect size is **0.00868009**, but because we are talking about removing an MV not an LV the previous rules of thumb 0.02 for weak, 0.15 for moderate and 0.35 for strong will likely not be appropriate to use here and I can't think of new ones atm.

This seems to be a valid transfer of Cohen's Idea, at least in my point of view, but I think thats not quite what you wanted so lets get crazy now.

```
#get path coefficient Image -> Expectation
ecsi$coefficients[25,2]

#get new path coefficient Image -> Expectation
excl_IMAG1_ecsi$coefficients[24,2]

#effect size of "IMAG1" on path coefficient Image -> Expectation
(fPath <- (ecsi$coefficients[25,2]-excl_IMAG1_ecsi$coefficients[24,2])/(1-excl_IMAG1_ecsi$coefficients[24,2]))
```

So now I tried to transfer Cohen's formula to path coefficients instead of rSquared Values. So we can see the effect of "IMAG1" on the path coefficient Image -> Expectation. It has changed from **0.5049139** to **0.4984685**.

The fpath formula will very likely be false, considering path coefficients can be negative too, but I don't have the time to think about that and I also think thats still not what you wanted in first place.

So now I'm taking you literally:

> "Now my question is: Is it possible to "back-calculate" the influence
>   of 0.505 to each IMAG1-5-variable?"

My first thought on that was: There can't be an influence of a path coefficient on and MV variable.

My second thought was: You mean the influence of LV "Expectation" to each MV IMAG1-5-variable, which is indeed represented through the path coefficient (which is 0.505).

My third thought was: There is no influence of LV "Expectation" to each MV IMAG1-5-variable, because "Image" is the endogenous and "Expectation" the exogenous variable. Which means "Image" does influence "Expectation", the arrow goes from "Image" to "Expectation".

Now I was curious, deleted the LV "Expectation" and calculated the model:

```
excl_exp_ecsi <- sempls(model=removeLVs(ECSImobi,"Expectation"), data=mobi, wscheme="pathWeighting")
excl_exp_ecsi
```

Now lets compare the outer loadings:

old ones:

```
lam_1_1               Image -> IMAG1    0.745
lam_1_2               Image -> IMAG2    0.599
lam_1_3               Image -> IMAG3    0.576
lam_1_4               Image -> IMAG4    0.769
lam_1_5               Image -> IMAG5    0.744
```

new ones:

```
lam_2_1              Image -> IMAG1    0.747
lam_2_2              Image -> IMAG2    0.586
lam_2_3              Image -> IMAG3    0.575
lam_2_4              Image -> IMAG4    0.773
lam_2_5              Image -> IMAG5    0.750
```

As you can see in the following visualisation of the ecsi model, "Image" is an exogenous, means independent latent Variable.

But there is still a slight change in the outer loadings as you can see in the two tables above, when deleting the "Expectation" variable. Now I can't tell you exactly why that is, because I do not know the algorithm good enough, but I hope I could clarify some things for you or other readers and not make it worse :).

[image: ECSI model]

Please note that I did not do research on that topic in literature and it just represents my idea how these could be calculated. There could also be a common way to do that and my approach could be deadly wrong.